# Find the first non repeating character in a given string from any language in the world

Tags: c++, string

> Find the first non repeating character in a given string. You may assume that the string contains any character from any language in the world

I did not understand "any language" if it is simply a string of all ASCII characters.

Then my solution is:

```
   // define a 
  bool  a[256];
   string b = "RAFAEL NADAL is KING OF CLAY";
   while (i < str.length())
     {
       int val = b[i];
        if (a[val])
            return false;
        else
            a[val] = true;
     }
```

with the above method by manuplating some thing we can get first non repeating character
but I am not understanding "from any language" (i.e Spanish, Arabic, etc.)

Comment: "any language in the world" might imply that some characters are multi-byte.  Does the full question mention anything about character encodings (e.g. utf8, utf16)?

Comment: If your strings are not large enough, you can think about storing them in a hashtable and for each character you enter, make a check if the character is already inserted in the hashtable(which takes O(1) time). So, you basically dont need to know all the languages as hashcode for each character should be unique.

Comment: It looks like your actually finding the first repeating character not the first non repeating character

Comment: You're invoking undefined behavior because you're checking `if (a[val])` but the value at that index could potentially be uninitialized.

Comment: @0x499602D2 the array should also be bools, if you see how he uses it not chars

Comment: There are so many problems with this code, why did you even bother posting it? Your while loop only has one statement inside it, which is `val` declaration. You do not change the value of `i`, meaning the loop is infinite. You use `val` outside of its scope, which would not even compile.

Comment: Use `char` array as bitmap and store only binary `1` a `0` and use bit masks, etc. You use 8x more memory than needed :)

Comment: @riv: Where does he use `val` outside of its scope? But I must agree, it's stupid :)

Comment: sry every one i did not write full code it is something lika aa pseudo code

Comment: @bartimar he had no brackets around the while before he edited it

Comment: I'm wondering if this would be the correct program to give to him. Can anyone assess? -- http://ideone.com/H5LDWr#view_edit_box

Comment: @0x499602D2 i dont need it i know how to do it

Comment: It's just that your assignment wants you to assume that the string contains any character, so I am using `std::wstring` and `wchar_t` for Unicode.

Comment: How can the standard ASCII character set support any (all) languages in the world? (This is what Unicode is for).

Comment: Why not ask your professor for clarification? We are just guessing what the assignment means. Just go to the source to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int firstNonRepeatingCharIndex(char* str)
{
    for ( int i = 0 ; *(str+i) ; i++)
    {
        int flag = 0;
        for ( int j = i+1 ; *(str+j) ; j++)
        {
            if ( *(str+i) == *(str+j))
                flag = 1;
        }
        if(flag == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```